# Pop head element in stack C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, stack

I am having trouble implementing a function that deletes the first element from a stack. (I know for sure that the stack has minimum two elements)

```
typedef struct Node {
    T value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct Stack {
    Node *head;

} Stack;

void Pop(Stack **st) {
    if (!IsEmptyStack(*st)) {
        Node* aux = (*st)->head;
        (*st)->head = (*st)->head->next;

    }
}
```

but same happens... `Segmentation fault.`

How can I fix the pop function?

Here are the other functions i'm using:

```
void InitStack(Stack **st)
{
    (*st) = (Stack *) malloc(sizeof(Stack *));
    (*st)->head = NULL;

}

int IsEmptyStack (Stack *st)
{
    if (!st)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: why you are passing **st instead of just *st ?

Comment: Code looks ok (as in shouldn't cause seg fault). The problem is probably in the code that creates the stack.

Comment: @JoulinRouge It is a school assignment and i can't modify the function's definition

Comment: maybe the problem is in the rest of the program, have you tried debugging? Where does it stops exactly?

Comment: Maybe a `Stack**` is passed since this `Stack` definition may be based on a definition of a singly-linked list, in which case dealing with pointers-to-pointers yields very elegant code in many cases.

Comment: Node* aux = (*st)->head->next; <- on this one . The other functions that i've used work fine.

Comment: Do you have the implementation of IsEmptyStack function ?

Comment: Did you initialize the node pointed by head? Maybe you initialize just the stack but you have to initialize at least two linked nodes to get the whole thing working

Comment: i've uploaded all the functions i'm using ..maybe that helps

Answer (score 0):

The first approach seems correct, but why do you pass a double pointer to the `Stack` to function `Pop`?  It seems `Pop` could be simplified this way:

```
typedef struct Node {
    T value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct Stack {
    Node *head;
} Stack;

void Pop(Stack *st) {
    if (!IsEmptyStack(st)) {
        Node *aux = st->head;
        st->head = aux->next;
        ... // dispose of aux appropriately
    }
}
```

Comment: @PetruGurita: if the prototype is fixed, your first code fragment looks correct, the problem is elsewhere, maybe in the `Stack` creation or pushing code.

Answer (score 0):

IsEmptyStack was wrong..
 instead of

```
int IsEmptyStack (Stack *st)
{
    if (!st)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I have to use

```
int IsEmptyStack (Stack *st)
{
    if (!st->head)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

That's because i've already allocated memory for st .. so checking st is irrelevant.